# Error 1064 when creating Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I am using MYSQL 5.6 and phpMyAdmin 4.1.14

I am trying to create a Trigger that will copy data from one db to another but get the following error:

*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'new.airplane_id,new.user_id,new.icao24,new.created_at,new.timestamp,new.altitude' at line 7*

Any pointers would be gratefully received

My code is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER airfields_insert 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON realtime 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
if (new.squawk between 6160 and 6167 or new.squawk between 6171 and 6177) and new.altitude <= 4000 then 
insert into airfields (airplane_id,user_id,icao24,created_at,timestamp,altitude,flight_number,latitude,longitude,heading,squawk,horizontal_speed,vertical_speed,Interested) (new.airplane_id,new.user_id,new.icao24,new.created_at,new.timestamp,new.altitude,new.flight_number,new.latitude,new.longitude,new.heading,new.squawk,new.horizontal_speed,new.vertical_speed,new.Interested);
end if;
```

Comment: Besides `VALUES` keyword you are also missing `END`  and you need DELIMITER

Answer (score 2):

You have Syntax error in insert query Your QUERY should be like that

```
insert into airfields (airplane_id,user_id,icao24,.......) 
values (new.airplane_id,new.user_id,new.icao24,........);
```

or simply

```
 insert into airfields values (new.airplane_id,new.user_id,new.icao24,........);
```

The form does not specify the column names where the data will be inserted, only their values:

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `VALUES` keyword in your `INSERT` statement

Your current `INSERT` query

```
insert into airfields (airplane_id,user_id,icao24,.......) 
(new.airplane_id,new.user_id,new.icao24,........);
end if;
```

It should be

```
insert into airfields (airplane_id,user_id,icao24,.......) 
values (new.airplane_id,new.user_id,new.icao24,........);
end if;
```

Also, you are missing the `END` keyword after `END IF`

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer Rahul. Unfortunately this does not do what I want. Once in effect, the trigger stops anything else going into the original table (realtime). I think that I will have to re-think the whole thing. Perhaps a trigger is not what I need for what I am trying to achieve.